# Magento 2: Shipping rates show 0 when there are more than one item in the cart

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I configure my store to use Flat Rate for shipping. When I add an item to cart, and go to checkout page, the shipping rate is there with my amount of money I configured (Let's say it's $20).

But **when I add one more item into the cart**, the shipping rate still shows up, *but the price now is **$0***. This only happens when there are more than one items in the cart, no matter whether they are the same product with the quantity of >1, or two different products.

Could anyone please help me to fix this problem? I use Magento version 2.0.7. If there is any needed information, please let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is probably a quirk of the sample-data, see this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140087/36044

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the cart price rule.

Go to Admin->Marketing->Promotions->Cart Price Rules