# Magento 2 - Shipping fee using table rates always zero when adding more items in cart

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, table-rates

I'm using "weight vs destination" and I have imported the csv successfully. I have checked the "shipping_tablerate" table and the data is correct.

When I added an item with weight = 1.00 to the cart, the shipping fee is correct. However, when I added another item with weight = 1.00 or added the same item again, the shipping fee is always zero. Why?

I'm using Magento v2.1.1 CE.

```
mysql> select * from shipping_tablerate where website_id = 1 and dest_country_id = 'HK';
+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------+
| pk | website_id | dest_country_id | dest_region_id | dest_zip | condition_name | condition_value | price  | cost   |
+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------+
| 31 |          1 | HK              |              0 | *        | package_weight |          0.0000 | 5.5000 | 0.0000 |
| 30 |          1 | HK              |              0 | *        | package_weight |          1.0100 | 6.5000 | 0.0000 |
| 29 |          1 | HK              |              0 | *        | package_weight |          2.0100 | 7.5000 | 0.0000 |
| 28 |          1 | HK              |              0 | *        | package_weight |          3.0100 | 8.5000 | 0.0000 |
+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My CSV file:

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"
HK,*,*,3.01,8.50
HK,*,*,2.01,7.50
HK,*,*,1.01,6.50
HK,*,*,0.00,5.50
```

Comment: Have you try below solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per magento default, table rates are working but also some cart rule is applying on shipping rates.

For Example when you add one product add to cart, table rates are working but when you add product **qty 2** and total is **greater than $50**  shipping rates not working. for this check below cart price rule.

There is one cart rule in admin which name is :

> Spend $50 or more - shipping is free!

`Admin >> Marketing  >> Cart Price Rules`

you can see here **Spend $50 or more - shipping is free!**

Disable this and check tables rates now, it's working for now.

Comment: Searching solution to my problem got me to this question. Can you help on this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217436/magento-2-shopping-cart-price-rule-table-rates-for-free-shipping-drop-off-s ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and  it's solved. The solution is below:
1, INACTIVE this cart rule , Spend $50 or more - shipping is free!
2, When you test one product, please  select a country, if you don't select a country, the system  can't judge the range of shipping fee.
[image]

Comment: Hi april.
Do you use default magento 2 Table Rate in this screen? or some custom modules?