# Magento 2.2.2 - Tablerates not working on Cart Page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, table-rates, zipcode

I am using `Tablerates` as my shipping method and the condition is set to `Price vs Destination`.

**Use case One**

```
Free Shipping over $200
```

**Use case Two**

```
If zip code falls under Zone 1 i.e. 28682-28685, `$20` flat rate shipping fee
```

**Use case Three**

```
If zip code falls under Zone 2 i.e. 28360-28365, `$50` flat rate shipping fee
```

Below is how my CSV looks like

```
 Country  Region/State Zip/Postal Code Order Subtotal(and above) Shipping Price                                                                                 
 USA      NC           28682           0                         20
 USA      NC           28682           201                       0                                  
 USA      NC           28360           0                         50
 USA      NC           28360           201                       0
```

Upload works, as is reflected in the table `shipping_tablerate` as seen in below image

[image: shipping-table]

But when user check shipping price on `cart` page for zip code whose shipping price should be `$20`, it always takes `$50`.  It can be seen in below image. Currently the user is logged in

[image: cart-estimate]

Although when `Subtotal` goes beyond `$200`, it shows shipping price `$0` which is correct as per **tablerates**. Moreover on checkout page, it shows correct shipping price based on zip code selected. It happens only on cart page.

Estimate Shipping and Tax also shows correct shipping price based on zip code entered. But when I click on selected price it throws below exception

`/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/totals-information 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Below is the response I get

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Cart\\Totals::setExtensionAttributes() 
must be an instance of Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\TotalsExtensionInterface, instance of Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtension given, called in \/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Api\/DataObjectHelper.php on line 125 and defined in \/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/Cart\/Totals.php:592\n
Stack trace:\n#0 \/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Api\/DataObjectHelper.php(125): 
Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Cart\\Totals->setExtensionAttributes(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtension))\n#1 \/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Api\/DataObjectHelper.php(85): 
Magento\\Framework\\Api\\DataObjectHelper->_setDataValues(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Cart\\Totals), Array, 'Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...')\n#2 \/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/Cart\/CartTotalRepository.php(103):
Magento\\Framework\\Api\\DataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Cart\\Tota' in '\/home\/storeq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/Cart\/Totals.php' on line 592","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}
```

> When user is not logged in, it does not show shipping charges, but
>   when user is logged in it always shows in correct shipping price i.e.
>   $50

- How do I resolve this and display correct shipping price on cart
  page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of `Free shipping is one of the most effective promotions you can offer. It can be based on a minimum purchase, or set up as a cart price rule that is applied when a set of conditions is met. If both apply to the same order, the configuration setting takes precedence over the cart rule.`

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-free.html

With the above in mind, you could also leverage price rules as a means of conditioning if the table rate options aren't meeting requirements.

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html

But judging from your request it should all be possible without any custom coding or 3rd party modules.

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Comment: You mean this should work - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218862/magento-2-2-2-tablerates-not-working-on-cart-page ?

Comment: `Sort the data by Region/State so the specific locations are at the top of the list, and the wildcard locations at the bottom. This will process the rules with the absolute values first, and the wildcard values later.` Also double check how the shipping configuration settings are configured. Also note that zipcode is only for each specific zipcode and not a range.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I know that error! I've had the `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals::setExtensionAttributes()` it's a magento bug I don't remember where I found it but here is the fix:

```
// open file /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository.php
// at line 97 add:
unset($addressTotalsData[\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);
```

try this and let me know.

Magento issue record:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9646

Fix:
https://github.com/ekuusela/magento2/commit/aa535ea5d4bf78915bddd4387a9d3c4b39943eea